# Need to sort Datetime

Tags: c#

I need to store collection of Inputtime(DateTime) and OutPutTime(Datetime) in variable then need to sort based upon input time.

What to use Dictionary,or ..?

Comment: Use a custom structure or a `Tuple`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is unordered, so no - don't use that.

Options:

- If you're using .NET 4.0, you could use a `Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>` for each item
- If it's all within one method, you could use an anonymous type
- You could create your own struct or class to hold the pair of "input time, output time"

However you do it, you would then use OrderBy from LINQ and then call ToList or ToArray if necessary, or create a `List<T>` and then call `Sort` with an appropriate comparator.

You *could* use `SortedList<,>` or `SortedDictionary<,>` but unless you *actually* need to look end times up by start times (instead of just iterating over them) these seem like inappropriate abstractions to me.

Answer (score 2):

Make a holder class (or just use an anonymous type - or a `Tuple` if you're using .NET4), add them to a List, then use LINQ. Something like this:

```
class Timeslot
{
    public DateTime InputTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime OutputTime { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var timeList = new List<Timeslot>(); 
    //populate the list
    var sortedList = timeList.OrderBy(t => t.InputTime).ToList();
}
```